# How can you query all the data with an empty set in cassandra db?

Tags: cassandra, cql

As the title says, I'm trying to query all the data I got with no value stored in it. I've been searching for a while, and the only operation allowed that I've found is `CONTAINS`, which doesn't fit my need.

consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE environment(
  id uuid,
  name varchar,
  message text,
  public Boolean,
  participants set<varchar>,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

How can I get all entries in the table with an empty set? E.g. participants = {} or null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you really can't.  Cassandra makes queries like this difficult by design, because there's no way it can be done without doing a full table scan (scanning each and every node).  This is why a big part of Cassandra data modeling is understanding all the ways that table will be queried, and building it to support those queries.

The other issue that you'll have to deal with, is that (generally speaking) Cassandra does not allow filtering by `null`s.  Again, it's a design choice...it's much easier to query for data that exists, rather than data that does not exist.  Although, when writing with [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html), there are ways around this one (using the `IF` clause).

If you knew all of the `id`s ahead of time, you could write something to iterate through them, `SELECT` and check for null on the app-side.  Although that approach will be slow (but it won't stress the cluster).  Probably the better approach, is to use a distributed OLAP layer like [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).  It still wouldn't be fast, but this is probably the best way to handle a situation like this.

Comment: Perhaps a column `participants_count INT` maintained by the application might be a _cheap_ workaround?